# WinAPI how to get the currently used font for a Window outside my application

Tags: winapi

I can get the current font for any window inside my application by sending that Window a `WM_GETFONT` message.
However if that Window is not owned by my application the `HFONT` returned will not make any sense.

How do I get the following (pseudo) code to work for windows not owned by my application?

```
HFONT childFont = (HFONT)SendMessage(childWin, WM_GETFONT, 0,0);
LOGFONT lf;
GetObject(hFont, sizeof(LOGFONT), &lf); 

//lf.lfFaceName will contain the font name.
```

Answer (score 4):

`WM_GETFONT` works fine cross-process, **provided that** the window you're sending it to responds to `WM_GETFONT`. This is only guaranteed for standard Windows controls.

Comment: Yes, but the `HFont` returned is meaningless outside the application it originates from.  That is the point. How do I make sense of the `HFont`?

Comment: The `HFONT` is not process-specific.  As long as you are querying a standard control that handles `WM_GETFONT` properly, the `HFONT` can be used across process boundaries.

Comment: The restrictions are even stronger: *... provided that the window ... responds to `WM_GETFONT`, and **doesn't lie** about it.* A window can use an arbitrary font for rendering, or even multiple fonts. The problem, however, is not in your answer. It's the question that is unanswerable.